# I want to use JavaScript value as argument of Controller function, how can I figure it out?

Tags: asp.net, razor

This is a controller function:

```
     public static void func(int id){

                     //some code
           }
```

and this is a JavaScript function:

```
     function notificationDivPressed(element,n) {
$(".NotificationDiv").removeAttr("style").children().removeAttr("style");
element = jQuery(element);
element.css("background", "#00b98d");
element.children().css("color", "white");
@MvcApplication.Controllers.MyController.func(n);
```

}

I want to do something like that... (use the "n" value a argument of "func" function from Controller)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC controler are http paths you cannot call a function in the controller you need to call a post or a get Method. This can be accomplished using ajax

Small snipit

in controlerr create method that looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public string Operation(string arg)
{
  return "";
}
```

in View ".cshtml" you can call this using ajax

I usualy take the lazy way out and use jquery

$.ajax({
            url: path to controler + '/Operation',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {arg:'Argument Value'},
            success: function (data) 
            {
            }});

you could add error handling in the jquery if you like.